# ESP8266 control relay

Tags: relay

The circuit is same as the first image of this link(http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html).

I am trying to use a pin from eps8266 as Vin connecting to the base of transistor (Vin) to control SRD-5VDC-SL, the transistor I used is 2N3904 NPN. The collector is connected to separate 5V power supply.

But this circuit cannot control the relay correctly.

I tested the transistor. Without turning on the 5V Vcc, but just applying Vin, transistor can work as switch,meaning the collector and emitter of transistor can be short or disconnected with Vin. But once the 5V power supply is on, the transistor cannot work as switch. I tested the resistance between collector and emitter with Vin applied, it is showing infinitely large resistance (but without turning on 5V power supply, it is showing close to 0 resistance).

And I also notice the resistance of relay coil is ~90 ohms without 5V voltage, but when applying 5V, it is ~13M ohms resistance.

I am really stuck here why the transistor cannot work as switch to control the relay when applying 5V power supply, and why the coil resistance varies with and without voltage applied.

Please help me and let me understand why this circuit cannot control the relay. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: Why there is no response to this question, no body has played with this circuit before or should I design another kind of circuit to control relay. I would appreciate any thoughts.